# Meteor 1.6.1.1 Docker meteorInstall is not defined

Tags: angular, docker, meteor, angular-meteor

i updated a project to Meteor version 1.6.1.1,
local its all running perfect, no errors all fine.

Then i tryed to dockerize it, first i had some problems with Javascript Heap out of Memory stuff, could fix that. But now...

Docker is built, starts and does not exit and App can be opened but nothing then loading animation happens because of this errors.

[image]

Does anyone know what the hack is happening in my docker container or knows how i can fix this?

Thanks a lot

regards Johannes 'xQp'

Comment: Your question doesn't give us a clue of what's happening inside the container/app, please adjust your question to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe your app is actually not installing everything that's needed? hard to tell.

Comment: Does your dockerfile run `meteor npm install`? Could be missing `@babel/runtime`?

Comment: there is no error msg inside my container, neither build nor running

Comment: but i found the problem, its froala:wysiwyg editor 
seems like i need to replace it with some other editor